# Calling an API without JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

I've been reading about making AJAX calls to external API's and people say that you HAVE to use JSONP otherwise you will get a 404 error.

However I am able to calling the following API: http://www.telize.com/ip with the following code

```js
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.telize.com/geoip",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.ip);
      $(".theTest").text(data.ip);
    },
    dataType: "JSON"

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it works for me perfectly.

This API is on an external server and I am able to get the data I want.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see in network console, it says response header value is = `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` .

**More info on Access-Control-Allow-Origin** According to same origin policy, if you invoke API existing on other domain, there will be error , [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Browser will say it is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue. To overcome this, API existing in other domain, has to allow you to invoke from your domain, i.e. just add the above header - [help](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header)

That is why you are able to invoke this from any domain. Have a look on following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: May be a little more explanation on the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and same origin policy would make the answer complete.

Comment: so they have included that in their response headers which allows any external app to access it? If they didn't include this additional header then I would have to use jsonp? is that correct?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao , i was just adding that, Thanks for commenting

Comment: @somango, yes, they have added to their response header to help others to invoke from any domain. I have updated my answer, just go through 2nd paragraph.